# Kafka Message getting replayed after containers restarted

Tags: go, apache-kafka, sarama

So, I have a long running process as a part of consumer which takes 5  minutes to complete.
I have set following values to avoid rebalance because of timeout issue.
c.Consumer.MaxProcessingTime = duration
c.Consumer.Group.Rebalance.Timeout = duration + 5*time.Second

And I am using Shopify sarama library in golang.
We have 3 containers and 1 partition(which we are going to increase soon). I observed one issue where when containers are restarted then all 3 containers started processing the last message.

Comment: Are the 3 consumers in the same consumer group?

Comment: Your consumers should be in one consumer group to avoid this behavior.